# Function pointer on object received by parameter

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a function which receives an object instance and a function pointer. How can I execute my function pointer on my object instance?

I have tried:

```
void    Myclass::my_fn(Object obj, bool (*fn)(std::string str))
{
   obj.fn("test"); // and (obj.fn("test"))
}
```

But nothing works. It tells me "unused parameters my_fn and fn"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `fn` is not a *member* function pointer of `Object`. For that you have to do e.g.

```
bool (Object::*fn)(std::string)
```

Then to call it you have to do

```
(obj.*fn)(...);
```

---

However, if your compiler and library can support C++11, I suggest you to use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
void MyclasS::my_fn(std::function<bool(std::string)> fn)
{
    fn("string");
}
```

Then call the `my_fn` function as

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // For `_1` below

Object obj;
myclassobject.my_fn(std::bind(&Object::aFunction, &obj, _1));
```

With `std::function` you can also use other function pointers or lambdas:

```
myclassobject.my_fn([](std::string s){ std::cout << s << '\n'; return true; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are something completely different form member function pointers (pointers to methods).

In case of function pointers, you don't need any object to call them:

```
void    Myclass::my_fn(bool (*fn)(std::string str))
{
   fn("test");
}
```

In case of member function pointers correct syntax would be:

```
void    Myclass::my_fn(Object obj, bool (Object::*fn)(std::string str))
{
   obj.*fn("test");
}
```